# Region difference not centered

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm subtracting a disk from a rectangle:

```
rec = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
dsk = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
recB = RegionDifference[rec, dsk];
RegionPlot[recB]
```

Why is the region plotted this way, and how do I solve this?

[image: rectangle with hole]

Comment: PlotPoints may help..

Comment: Basically, this is *Mathematica* trying to be clever about plot ranges. Sometimes it fails, as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 RegionPlot[recB, PlotRange -> RegionBounds@recB]
```

[image]